# dequeue (remove) woocommerce css stylesheets

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to dequeue the woocommerce style sheets from all pages except checkout/cart/receipt pages.

The code form the woocommerce help page (http://docs.woothemes.com/document/disable-the-default-stylesheet/) works to remove the stylesheets entirely.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_enqueue_styles', '__return_empty_array' );
```

I tried to use this code but it does not work:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_manage_woocommerce_styles', 99 );
function child_manage_woocommerce_styles() {
remove_action( 'wp_head', array( $GLOBALS['woocommerce'], 'generator' ));
if ( function_exists( 'is_woocommerce' ) ) {
    if ( ! is_woocommerce() && ! is_cart() && ! is_checkout() ) {
add_filter( 'woocommerce_enqueue_styles', '__return_empty_array' );
}}
}
```

Comment: I am trying to use the add_filter( 'woocommerce_enqueue_styles', '__return_empty_array' );. However, it isn't working for me. I place the code in the functions.php of my child theme. Any ideas why it isn't working?

Comment: **[This is a link to the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69339081/15040627)**

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are checking that the page is not all of it in once. You have to separate the `if` statements like:

```
if ( ! is_woocommerce()) {
  add_filter( 'woocommerce_enqueue_styles', '__return_empty_array' );
}}
if ( ! is_cart() ) {
  add_filter( 'woocommerce_enqueue_styles', '__return_empty_array' );
}}
if ( is_checkout() ) {
  add_filter( 'woocommerce_enqueue_styles', '__return_empty_array' );
}}
```

That should fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Change && with ||

```
    if ( function_exists( 'is_woocommerce' ) ) {
    if ( ! is_woocommerce() || ! is_cart() || ! is_checkout() ) {
add_filter( 'woocommerce_enqueue_styles', '__return_empty_array' );
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Deregister/Dequeue styles is best practice

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_deregister_style
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_style

But you can use this filter too, to filter out woocommerce styles with any condition.

```
add_filter( 'style_loader_src', function($href){
if(strpos($href, "name-of-allowed.css") !== false) {
return $href;
}
return false;
});
```