# How to remove the woocommerce.css file from the theme?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am using WordPress and I installed the Woocommerce plugin.

I added the template folder in my theme and started to customize my theme.

Now, I have to remove the `Woocommerce.css` from my theme and I found code on the official website [here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/disable-the-default-stylesheet/)

I added the same code in the function.php

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_enqueue_styles', '__return_empty_array' );
```

or

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_enqueue_styles', '__return_false' );
```

but both answers are not working. I have installed the 5.7.1 Woocommerce.

How can I solve this issue?

**function.php**

[image]

```
function customtheme_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'customtheme-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), time() );
    wp_style_add_data( 'customtheme-style', 'rtl', 'replace' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'customtheme-navigation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/navigation.js', array(), _S_VERSION, true );
    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }
    wp_dequeue_style( 'customtheme-woocommerce-style' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'customtheme_scripts' );
```

**view source**

The domain name is just an example.

[image]

Comment: For me add_filter( 'woocommerce_enqueue_styles', '__return_empty_array' ); works perfectly on Version 5.7.1 . Make sure u clear all cache.

Comment: @MartinMirchev, Yes,I tried that but it's not working.. I have my own custom theme and I added the above code in the function.php file.

Comment: i have tested on storefront and custom theme. Both works without issue.

Comment: @MartinMirchev, Just updated my code in the question. Can you please check it once?

Comment: From what i see in your screenshot your woocommerce.css is not from the plugin its in your theme ? The filter removes woocommerce.css file from woocommerce plugin. So in your case you have to wp_dequeue_style( 'customtheme-woocommerce-style' ); put it in your wp_enqueue_scripts action

Comment: @MartinMirchev, I updated the code again in the question. Can you please check it once?

Comment: Are you using child theme ? If its child theme override function.
If you use only parent then edit the function where you enqueue this file.

Comment: @MartinMirchev, I am using the parent theme. Yes, I found the enqueue code. It was in inc/woocommerce.php and it's working after commenting. Thank you so much for the help

Comment: Glad to help! Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 3):

> This answer has been fully tested on woocommerce `5.x+` and works fine on the default woo style sheets! If you're using a custom theme and/or custom style sheet then you may encounter some discrepancies.

What you see on the documentation page, no longer works on woo `4+`, [according to their github page](https://gist.github.com/woogists/8af93b901eac5d4dc2fb1452516c1079#gistcomment-3581623).

So you need to dequeue its styles!

> [`wp_dequeue_style`<sup>Docs</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dequeue_style/)

So if you only want to remove `woocommerce.css` file, then you could do this:

```php
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'removing_woo_styles');

function removing_woo_styles()
{
  wp_dequeue_style('woocommerce-general'); // This is "woocommerce.css" file
}
```

However, if you want to remove all of the style sheets loaded by woo, then you could use this:

```php
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'removing_woo_styles');

function removing_woo_styles()
{
  wp_dequeue_style('wc-block-vendors-style');
  wp_dequeue_style('wc-block-style');
  wp_dequeue_style('woocommerce-general');
  wp_dequeue_style('woocommerce-layout');
  wp_dequeue_style('woocommerce-smallscreen');
}
```

If you still can see the styles, then try to clean your cache.

---

##### UPDATE related to the question "custom style sheet"

At the time that I was writing the answer you had not provided any screenshot of your style sheet, nor did you say anything about using a custom style sheet. That's why you were not able to get it to work.

> ##### Please do NOT copy/paste if you're using a custom style sheet, like the custom css file used in the question. `wp_dequeue_style` function takes your style sheet handle as the argument. So please read the documentation first. You're using a custom handle name (i.e "customtheme-woocommerce-style"), therefore, you need to use that handle name.

```php
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'removing_woo_styles');

function removing_woo_styles()
{
  wp_dequeue_style('customtheme-woocommerce-style'); // This is your "custom style sheet" file.
}
```

Also note that commenting out the enqueue section in the main file (i.e `inc/woocommerce.php`) may work temporarily but on the next woo update, it'll come back again. So, it's recommended to avoid updating your template files as much as possible unless you really have to which is not the case here!

Comment: I tried your answer but that also not working, Clear the cache, Updated the browser but still showing the woocommerce.css file when I check the view source.

Comment: It's because your css "handle" is called "customtheme-woocommerce-style". At the time that i was writing the answer you had not provided any screenshot of your style sheet, nor did you say anything about using a custom them. That's why you were not able to get it to work. I just updated my answer, take a look at it and give it a shot!

Comment: Yes you are right, If I update the Woocommerce then it will come again but somewhere I had read the post that I have to add the template folder in my theme and I can edit according to the requirement in that template itself. I did the same.

Comment: I know, I have to mention that I am using a custom theme. I thought everyone doing the same as I did for woocommerce. I apologize for the misscommunication from my side.

Comment: Not a problem. It happens! Yes you could "override" the template parts, but again it makes your life harder in the long run. On every update, you have to check compatibility of your templates with the updated ones. Anyways, try to pass your css file "handle name" to the `wp_dequeue_style` function and see if you could remove it. If that works, then you don't have to worry about templates anymore! Using wordpress hooks is much more continent than "overriding" templates.